# UICollectionView cell scrolling issue in ios

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uicollectionview

On reloading the UICollectionView some time CollectionView cell does not bounce back.[image: See the image.] see the image collectionCell with title "Bgrawal ji Sourabh" should not be at this much distance from right side.It should have bounce.

Comment: Use "scrollRectToVisible"

Comment: what you mean with "right" (left?) side?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[self.collectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:yourDesiredIndexPath atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically animated:NO];
```

Comment: is there any setting or flag that i can set. I think this should be the default behaviour of UICollectionView like UITableView does.

Comment: Reloading TableView or CollectionView does not bounce you back to top or bottom. If your CollectionView was vertical then you could easily call scrollToTop or scrollToBottom. But in this case, you have to move to your first cell forcefully.

Answer (score 0):

Please add below code before when your reload your collectionView

```
let indexes = NSIndexPath(forItem: 0, inSection: 0)
self.collectionViewSecond.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexes, atScrollPosition: .None, animated: false)
```

It's work for me hope work for you also!

Comment: it always scroll to collection to display first cell. I dont want that scrolling should work only if last cell is far from right end.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Make sure you have enabled these two option in the `CollectionView` `attribute Inspector` i.e. `Bounce on Scroll` and `Bounce on zoom` this will allow the `collectionView` to give a bounce feed back on the scroll.